# Find the value of $\mathbf{r'_1}\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Suppose that $\mathbf{r}(t)$ is a smooth vector-valued function of $t$ with $\mathbf{r'}(1)=⟨\sqrt{3},-\sqrt{3},-1⟩$, and let $\mathbf{r_1}(t)$ be defined by the equation $\mathbf{r_1}(t)=\mathbf{r}(2\cos t)$. Then $$\mathbf{r'_1}\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)=?$$

I am confused with $\mathbf{r_1}(t)=\mathbf{r}(2\cos t)$. Did it mean $\mathbf{r_1}(t)=\mathbf{r}(t)(2\cos t)?$ If does Then 
\begin{align}
\mathbf{r'_1}(t)&=\mathbf{r'}(t)(-2\sin t)\\
\mathbf{r'_1}\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)&=\mathbf{r'}\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)\left(-2\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)\right)\\
&=?\quad(-\sqrt{3}) \qquad\text{As we only know }\mathbf{r'}(1)
\end{align}
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: No, they’re referring to composition of functions.

Comment: @juandiegorojas Ok eventually if it is composition I also can't see how to get $\mathbf{r}(2\cos t)=⟨?,?,?⟩$

Comment: since we don’t know $\mathbf{r}$ then we cannot explicitly write $\mathbf{r}_1$. However, you may use change rule to calculate $\mathbf{r}_1’(\pi/3)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in differentiating $\mathbf{r}_1$ to

$$\mathbf{r}'_1(t) = \mathbf{r}'(t) (-2 \sin t)$$

You forgot the inner part of the chain rule within $\mathbf{r}'$: remember that

$$D[f \circ g] = (f' \circ g) \cdot g'$$

i.e.

$$\frac{d}{dt} f(g(t)) = f'(g(t)) g'(t)$$

so you must instead have the identity

$$\mathbf{r}'_1(t) = [\mathbf{r}'(2 \cos t)] \cdot (-2 \sin t)$$

Note the difference? Try it now - what is $2 \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)$? Notice something?

Comment: Aha! $\mathbf{r'}(2cos\left(\frac{\pi }{3}\right))=\mathbf{r'}(1)$ Which was given

Comment: @NajmunNahar : Yup!